# Google Chrome extension to save a web page as PDF on Dropbox

Tags: pdf, chrome, backup, dropbox

I am looking for a Google Chrome extension that can save a web page as PDF on Dropbox (e.g. by a simple click on the extension icon at the right of the address bar, or right clicking on the page). I don't want to manually have to save the page as PDF then send in to my Dropbox account.

I use Google Chrome on Windows 7.

Comment: If anyone has any idea

Comment: please add an answer.

Comment: I haven't found anything so far.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look, it doesn't seem like there's an extension that does exactly what you ask.

There is an extension that is close however; [Save As PDF](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-as-pdf/kpdjmbiefanbdgnkcikhllpmjnnllbbc?hl=en). It will save a webpage as a PDF, and it's quite nice on its implementation. There is a paid version that features password locking, page sizes, etc (it's 9.99 a year if those interest you).

One workaround using this is use the extension to save the pdf, then just move the pdf into your dropbox folder on Windows (if you have the desktop client that is)...

Comment: Thanks, works good indeed, I used it a few times.